# Java. Как сделать ожидание? Часть 2 (делаю секундомер).

Tags: java

Всем привет! Сделал вот такой код:

```
 public class Stopwatch {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int i = 1;
        int b = 0; 
                while (i<61) {
            System.out.println("Количество секунд: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i++;}
                if(i>=60){
                    b++;
                }
            if(i>=61) {
                i-=60;
                while (i<60){
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("Количество минут: " + b + " Количество секунд: "
 + i );

            }
             }
     }
```

Хочу чтоб когда доходило до 60, секунды сбрасывались, но появлялись минуты и т.д. Но у меня не получается. Подскажите, где ошибка!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int seconds = 0, minutes = 0;
while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    seconds++;
    if (minutes != 0)
        System.out.print(minutes + ":");
    System.out.println(seconds);
    if (seconds == 59) {
        seconds = -1;
        minutes++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 while (i<61) {
            System.out.println("Количество секунд: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i++;
 }
 System.out.println("Количество минут: " + i/60 + " Количество секунд: " + i%60 );
```

Comment: спасибо, но не совсем то, т.к. он не разделяет на минуты и секунды если мне надо больше минуты...

Comment: Как это не разделяет?

Comment: если я в while (i<61) пишу 700, к примеру, разделения нету...

Comment: Ну да, не очень внимательно прочитал условие. Тогда @Kremchik написал вариант тот, что надо.

Answer (score 0):

Тут всё просто, например, если ты хочешь сделать таймер на 1 секунду (1 секунда = 1000 милисекунд). То что я выделил жирным нужно обязательно вставить в код!

```
public class main (public static void main(String[] args) **throws InterruptedException** {

 //Таймер 1 минута
 Thread.sleep(1000);

 //Таймер 2 минуты
 Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

и т.д. Это мой первый ответ, не судите строго :)